# Which plotting backends does pandas support for DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

pandas does allow plotting with third party [plotting backends](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#plotting-backends). I know that [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/) (the default one) and [`hvplot`](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/) are supported as plotting backends. But I could not find a complete list of supported backends yet. Which plotting backends are supported right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need pandas >= 0.25 to change the plotting backend.

These are the available plotting backends that I know of:

- [matplotlib](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)
- [hvplot >= 0.5.1](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Pandas_API.html)
- [holoviews](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Pandas_API.html)
- [pandas_bokeh](https://github.com/PatrikHlobil/Pandas-Bokeh)
- [plotly >= 4.8](https://plotly.com/python/pandas-backend/)
- [altair](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair_pandas)

You can set the backend for the whole session as follows:

```
pd.options.plotting.backend = 'plotly'
```

Or for just one plot like this:

```
df.plot(backend='plotly')
```

See also: 
[Change pandas plotting backend to get interactive plots instead of matplotlib static plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58440524/change-pandas-plotting-backend-to-get-interactive-plots-instead-of-matplotlib-st)