# Is there a way to list all available third-party plotting backends in pandas (programmatically, in Python code)?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, data-visualization

In Pandas, the list of available plotting backends changes and get updated over time, but is there a function/attribute to actually print them?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#plotting-backends

I understand I can query the existing one like this:

```
print(pd.options.plotting.backend)
matplotlib
```

Or, for example, if I need all the templates in plotly, I can write:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.templates
```

And then I get:

```
Default template: 'plotly'
Available templates:
    ['ggplot2', 'seaborn', 'simple_white', 'plotly',
     'plotly_white', 'plotly_dark', 'presentation', 'xgridoff',
     'ygridoff', 'gridon', 'none']
```

Is is possible to get such information for the available pandas plotting backends, too?

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting pandas internal function `_load_backend` in the module `pandas.plotting._core.py` you can print some of the available plotting backed using the code:

```
from importlib.metadata import entry_points
eps = entry_points()
if "pandas_plotting_backends" in eps:
    print([entry_point.name for entry_point in eps["pandas_plotting_backends"])
```

This list is partial because if you try to load a backend which doesn't appear in this list than it will fallback is to use `importlib.import_module`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way of getting a list, but in the question/answer here are the available backends that I know of:

[Which plotting backends does pandas support for DataFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271440/which-plotting-backends-does-pandas-support-for-dataframes)

In short:
**matplotlib, plotly, altair, holoviews, hvplot, pandas_bokeh**.

You need to have the plotting library installed for it to work as a plotting backend.

You can set the backend for the whole session as follows:

```
pd.options.plotting.backend = 'plotly'
```

Or for just one plot like this:

```
df.plot(backend='plotly')
```